# ProximityAlert management

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, android-pendingintent, proximity

I've a list of GeoPoint that I put on a MapView as interest point. I've added a proximity alert to all of this GeoPoint. I've implemented the onReceive method in the BroadcastReceiver and it works fine. My problem is: how can I get what proximity alert was triggered? I've to implement an AlertDialog with some information about the specific interest point.